# Spring Boot not starting as a standalone jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I am creating a independent jar using Spring Boot using Export command with Runnable Jar and trying to run the jar in command prompt but it is throwing the below error, the same application is running within eclipse. I cannot use maven and I am not using spring-boot-thymeleaf also in my application. Even after adding spring-boot-autoconfigurator-thymeleaf jar also I am getting this error.

```
2017-04-19 19:32:55.320  INFO 26320 --- [           main] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/C:/Users/XXX/Downloads/mySpringBoot.jar]
2017-04-19 19:32:55.321  INFO 26320 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report enabled debug logging (start with --debug)


Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.thymeleaf.ThymeleafAutoConfiguration$ThymeleafViewResolverConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.spri
ngframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.thymeleaf.ThymeleafAutoConfiguration$ThymeleafViewResolverConfiguration.templateEngine; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.f
actory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.thymeleaf.ThymeleafAutoConfiguration$ThymeleafDefaultConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
autowire field: private final java.util.Collection org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.thymeleaf.ThymeleafAutoConfiguration$ThymeleafDefaultConfiguration.templateResolvers; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframew
ork.boot.autoconfigure.thymeleaf.ThymeleafAutoConfiguration$DefaultTemplateResolverConfiguration': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find template location: class path resource [templates/] (are you really using Thymeleaf?)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:120)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:619)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:306)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:880)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:869)
        at hello.Application.main(Application.java:14)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.thymeleaf.ThymeleafAutoConfiguration$ThymeleafViewResolverConfiguration.templateEngine; nested exception is org.spri
ngframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.thymeleaf.ThymeleafAutoConfiguration$ThymeleafDefaultConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationEx
ception: Could not autowire field: private final java.util.Collection org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.thymeleaf.ThymeleafAutoConfiguration$ThymeleafDefaultConfiguration.templateResolvers; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with nam
e 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.thymeleaf.ThymeleafAutoConfiguration$DefaultTemplateResolverConfiguration': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find template location: class path resource [templates/] (are you really using Thymeleaf
?)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
        ... 16 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.thymeleaf.ThymeleafAutoConfiguration$ThymeleafDefaultConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.fac
tory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private final java.util.Collection org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.thymeleaf.ThymeleafAutoConfiguration$ThymeleafDefaultConfiguration.templateResolvers; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error cre
ating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.thymeleaf.ThymeleafAutoConfiguration$DefaultTemplateResolverConfiguration': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find template location: class path resource [templates/] (are you rea
lly using Thymeleaf?)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:370)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1094)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:989)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:957)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
        ... 18 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private final java.util.Collection org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.thymeleaf.ThymeleafAutoConfiguration$ThymeleafDefaultConfiguration.templateResolvers; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.
factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.thymeleaf.ThymeleafAutoConfiguration$DefaultTemplateResolverConfiguration': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find template location: class
 path resource [templates/] (are you really using Thymeleaf?)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
        ... 38 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.thymeleaf.ThymeleafAutoConfiguration$DefaultTemplateResolverConfiguration': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException:
 Cannot find template location: class path resource [templates/] (are you really using Thymeleaf?)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1545)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:370)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1094)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:989)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:909)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
        ... 40 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find template location: class path resource [templates/] (are you really using Thymeleaf?)
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:385)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.thymeleaf.ThymeleafAutoConfiguration$DefaultTemplateResolverConfiguration.checkTemplateLocationExists(ThymeleafAutoConfiguration.java:87)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:300)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:133)
        ... 61 more
```

Please suggest know why I am getting this error and I need to start the spring boot application jar as export->Runnable jar (as I cannot use maven to generate jar) and I should not get the above exception.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find template location: class path resource [templates/] (are you really using Thymeleaf?)

Comment: Spring tries to autoconfigure Thymeleaf, which causes the error. You do not need Thymeleaf, right? If that is correct, try figuring out why Thymeleaf is loaded. The Spring output mentions a debug flag which you should try.

Comment: Spring Boot requires a certain directory structure within the JAR. The Maven and Gradle plugin will create it automatically for you, however if you create the JAR yourself, you have to make sure that it has the structure which is needed. You can find out more about the structure in the documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#executable-jar

Comment: If legacy XML jars are a problem, you might be able to use the maven build jar if you specify `-Djava.endorsed.dirs` on startup.

Answer (score 1):

I am risking to get some downvotes but I think without maven you cannot include everything needed for a spring boot application to run because in the maven pom.xml you are including not only the dependencies, but also few plugins like tomcat plugin. So the next step for you is to start using build management tool as you are working with spring and spring boot that is almost mandatory in my oppinion. Maven is hard to master but easy to start and use so better take a look at this official simple tutorial: https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html

Comment: Your answer is basically correct. Spring Boot requires a certain directory structure within the JAR, which is automatically created by the Maven or Gradle plugins. If the OP wants to create the JAR himself, he has to make sure that the structure is as expected.

Comment: there are some plugins in some projects (tomcat is almost always included) that maybe cannot be included in the way the app expects them. Not sure what the maven plugin tag is doing but I think you cannot resolve that thing with simply including everything in the project build path

Comment: There are some dependencies which cannot be included in maven for xml creation (even included by pushing jar to repo) so I tried to create a standalone jar. Will it be possible to achieve using ant build where using maven the other jar structure is not properly working while creating xml. So Is it not possible to run the spring boot without maven and but the same is working within my eclipse.

Comment: If you can include them manualy in build path maven can include them too. Maybe share your pom.xml and we can resolve the problems